# Update or saveorUpdate in CRUDRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I know there's already a similar question answered previously, but my problem is implementing save with update while there are 3 methods in the interface.
I'm currently using the following methods in my project and don't know how to make saveOrUpdate in this.
The following are my classes:

```
   public interface CompanyRepository extends CrudRepository<Company,Long>{
   Company findByCompanyName (String companyName);
   List<Company> findAll();
   Company findById(Long id);
   }
```

The following is part of my Company Class

```
@Entity
public class Company extends BaseEntity{
 @NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 16)
private String companyName;
@Length(max = 60)
private String desc;
//TODO max: add LOGO class later for pic saving
@OneToMany
private List<MobileModel> mobileModels;

public Company()
{
  super();
  mobileModels = new ArrayList<>();
  }

//Getters n setters
 }
```

The following is my baseEntity clas

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.AUTO)
protected final Long id;

@Version
private Long version;  
//Getters n setters
}
```

Thanks in advance.
I read everywhere and tried so many things for 5 hours. 
I just want CompanyRepository to implement all 3 methods without me overriding them in some other class but if I have too then explain how because part of my code is dependent on CompanyRepository. I just wish to add save with update, please explain with respect to my code.

Answer (score 107):

`CrudRepository` has only `save` but it acts as `update` as well.

- When you do `save` on entity with empty `id` it will do a `save`.
- When you do `save` on entity with existing `id` it will do an `update` that means that after you used `findById` for example and changed something in your object, you can call `save` on this object and it will actually do an `update` because after `findById` you get an object with populated `id` that exist in your DB.
- `save` in `CrudRepository` can accept a single entity or `Iterable` of your entity type.

Comment: I was looking for an explanation like this! Easy and simple to understand ! Thanks!

Comment: @Tom: Is it the same for `saveAll` as well?

Comment: @TheOddAbhi under the hood `saveAll` just iterate and call `save` for each element in the provided Iterable. So yes, it is the same (e.g. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L589)

Comment: This must be selected as answer, voted up ++

Comment: you can do save, sending the changed values ​​with the same ID in POST request, this will also update directly.

Answer (score 1):

putting below if check resolve my issue and save method is working as save and update both when i pass id it updates the record in database and when i dont pass id it save new record in database 
place is incoming object in my case and new place is new object of place in which i am setting the place id

```
    if(place.getPlaceId()!=0)
        newPlace.setPlaceId(place.getPlaceId());
```